# jq is not printing the lines where select() returns null

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to fetch all the ec2 instances from AWS using awscli with Tag Name.
command I used is

```
aws ec2 describe-instances | \
jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[] | (.Tags[] | select(.Key == "Name") | .Value) + " " \
+ .InstanceId + " " + .InstanceType + " " + .KeyName + " " + .PrivateIpAddress + " " + .PublicIpAddress'
```

Here, jq is printing the instances only with tag Name, and other instances which don't have tag name are not printed.
am I using the select() in wrong way?

Actual output:

```
master-bastion i-026b52da57ae3a85 t2.micro aus 10.90.0.68 52.62.76.17
master-mongodb_1 i-083bceea3aea1832 t3.medium aus 10.90.100.25
master-mongo i-06d669ba5cda0c74 t3.medium aus 10.90.100.12
master-solr1 i-09752d54fe143fec t2.medium aus 10.90.100.12
master-solr2 i-039bf2028ec15d97 t2.medium aus 10.90.101.22
master-solr3 i-09fc04ceeeb1efae t2.medium aus 10.90.100.6
rabbitmq-1 i-0125de65ba60627a t2.small aus 10.90.100.10
rabbitmq-2 i-069d546deb4a1c23 t2.small aus 10.90.101.11
```

Expected Output:

```
master-bastion i-026b52da57ae3a85 t2.micro aus 10.90.0.68 52.62.76.17
i-06d669ba5cda0c4d t3.medium aus 10.90.100.142
i-062669ba5cda0sfs t3.medium aus 10.90.100.147
master-mongodb_1 i-083bceea3aea1832 t3.medium aus 10.90.100.25
master-mongo i-06d669ba5cda0c74 t3.medium aus 10.90.100.12
master-solr1 i-09752d54fe143fec t2.medium aus 10.90.100.12
master-solr2 i-039bf2028ec15d97 t2.medium aus 10.90.101.22
master-solr3 i-09fc04ceeeb1efae t2.medium aus 10.90.100.6
rabbitmq-1 i-0125de65ba60627a t2.small aus 10.90.100.10
rabbitmq-2 i-069d546deb4a1c23 t2.small aus 10.90.101.11
```

Comment: Can you provide some input data along with the actual output and what you expected it to be?

Comment: updated question.

Comment: You can use `[ ..... .ImageId , .InstanceId, .KeyName, .PrivateIpAddress, .PublicIpAddress ] | join(" ")` for the last part of the concatenation

Comment: If no tag exists with the given name then `select` will not produce anything and the filter around it will indeed not produce anything.

Comment: @Botje Yes. But it should print the other values right?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan when I used join(), I am getting error like can't concatenate string with integer.

Comment: No, select _does not produce any value_ if the filter does not match.

Comment: Since you need an array before using `join`. The square brackets are used for converting this combination of columns to an array within the above suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we focus on just the tags, I see two solutions:

```
(.Tags[] | select(.Key == "Name")).value // ""
```

This uses the `//` operator to return `""` in case the .value does not exist.

Alternatively, you can shoehorn the tags into an object first:

```
.Tags | map({key: .Key, value: .Value}) | from_entries | .Name // ""
```

Comment: a typo in your answer. update `name` to `Name`. thanks